# Change sharing icons in woocommerce single product pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, share, product

In WooCommerce I am using a Storefront child theme. I want to change Social media icons location in single product pages. I want to place them under images. By default, they are placed under meta.

I am adding following code in `functions.php` *(in my child theme)*:

```
/* Enter your custom functions here */
add_action('woocommerce_before_single_product_summary','woocommerce_template_single_sharing',30);

// Remove Sharing icons
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_sharing',50);
```

But is doesn't work.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To move sharing icons location, you can try this instead:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'move_template_single_sharing', 5 );
function move_template_single_sharing(){

    // Remove Sharing icons
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_sharing', 50 );

    // New Sharing icons location
    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_sharing', 30 );
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

tested and works

Comment: Is it possible to place Icons under Image Gallery?

Comment: This is much more complicated… I think that it can only be done with some CSS styling and by [overriding WooCommerce  templates via the theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/) as you should need to make some html structural changes. It depend also on your theme CSS… So please, may be you could mark this answer as accepted as I am making the code working. Then you could ask a new question adding my answer code and explaining that it doesn't work to add the icons below the image. you should include a live link to your web site too.